# Is it possible to ask the user to pick what class they'd like to run and then run that class?

Tags: java

I'm new to JAVA programming, and was wondering if it's possible/how to ask the user to input what class they'd like to run and then call/run that class?

Example:
I created two classes to solve the Towers of Hanoi given (supplied by user) n amount of disks.  One class solves the puzzle recursively and the other class solves the puzzle iteratively.  When I am asking the user for the number of disks they'd like to use, is it possible to ask them how they would like to solve the program whether it be recursively or iteratively and then call the class that they chose?

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for a [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)). See [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)#Encapsulation) in particular.

Comment: Yes, it's called an **`if` statement**. Ask the user to enter 1 for recursive, or 2 for iterative, then write `if (choice == 1) { Recursive.run(noOfDisks); } else if (choice == 2) { Iterative.run(noOfDisks); } else { print("Invalid option"); }`

Comment: @Andreas of course I had to over-engineer it, lest they revoke my "coder credentials"

Comment: The question is simply how to choose, at runtime, the right method from the right class, depending on the input. Create two static methods in each class, and switch the input to run them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a pretty straightforward manner using a common interface both solvers implement.

```java
interface HanoiSolver {
    void solve(int n);
}
```

```java
// iterative solver
class IterativeHanoi implements HanoiSolver {
    public void solve(int n) { ... }
}
```

```java
// iterative solver
class RecursiveHanoi implements HanoiSolver {
    public void solve(int n) { ... }
}
```

```java
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // you can change this to read input however you like
       String userInput = args[0];
       Integer n = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

       HanoiSolver solver;
       if (userInput.equals("recursive")) {
            solver = new RecursiveHanoi();
       } else {
            solver = new IterativeHanoi();
       }
       solver.solve(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: ,I think you forgot to use "new" in front of the constructors of RecursiveHanoi() and IterativeHanoi().

Comment: @MLavrentyev thanks so much for your help and javaguy for catching that :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible.

This version may look a bit more complicated on first glance, but it separates the parts more clearly. The interface and the classes would usually be in separate files in real applications. Also, the static `chooseSolver` - method would possible be moved to a separate class named something like `SolverFactory`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    interface Solver {
        void solveIt();
    }

    static class SuperSolver implements Solver {
        public void solveIt() {
            System.out.println("SuperSolver always solves anything");
        }
    }

    static class FastSolver implements Solver {
        public void solveIt() {
            System.out.println("Noone beats the FastSolver");
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String in = askUserForOption();
        Solver s = chooseSolver(in);
        s.solveIt();
    }

    private static String askUserForOption() {
        String in;
        Set<String> validOptions = Set.of("A", "B");        
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            do {
                System.out.print("Enter A or B: ");
                in = sc.nextLine();
            } while (!validOptions.contains(in));
        }
        return in;
    }

    private static Solver chooseSolver(String in) {
        switch (in) {
        case "A":
            return new SuperSolver();
        case "B":
            return new FastSolver();
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("something went terribly wrong - an invalid option was given");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where this code is used internally or as library package.
Internally you can use interface and then seperate out the concrete implementation.

In library , you can again let user call interface method , write implementation of that interface based on condition.

Or if you want the user to determine the algo to use during the runtime then use Reflection to decide which class's object to create.